# Validar una Lista con Data Annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp

Buenas tengo una lista de objetos ,cada objeto tiene un checkbox, si el checkbox es verdadero quiero validar que el campo Nombre y el campo Apellido tengan un valor.

Mi modelo:

```
[ListHasElements(ErrorMessage : "Debe escribir en los casilleros")]
public List<MyObjeto> ListaMyObjeto { get; set; }
```

este lista contiene los siguientes campos:

```
public class MyObjeto{
public bool IsCheck { get; set; }
public string Nombre { get; set; }
public string Apellido { get; set; }
}
```

Esta es my clase personalizada

```
public class ListHasElements : ValidationAttribute
{

    public override bool IsValid(List<PlanillaResult> list)
    {
        if (list != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if (item.IsCheck == true)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Nombre) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Apellido))
                    {

                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        return list.Any();
    }
}
```

Pero me tira el siguiente error:"no se encontró ningún miembro adecuado para invalidar".

Quizás me falte algo sencillo o lo estoy haciendo mal,lo que necesito es validar una lista por medio de  Data Annotations

Comment: ¿No te falta poner el sufijo `Attribute` en tu clase personalizada? Así: `ListHasElementsAttribute`.

Comment: Hola, qué problema tienes? No lo has dejado muy claro la verdad. Cuando validas tu modelo que no cumple tu especificacion, ves si te devuelve errores? Haces un `if (ModelState.IsValid)` en tu controlador?

Comment: Sergio, El Problema es que me salta este error: "no se encontró ningún miembro adecuado para invalidar"  quizas me falte algo sencllo, es la primera vez que uso esto, Saludos.

Comment: @KroneauxSchneider Si bien es verdad que por convencion se le coloca attribute, no es lo que influye en el codigo.Saludos